# Android - Avoid saving to storage/emulated/0

Tags: android, image, android-studio, save, public

I'm trying to save an image on the public storage directory using the below code. However, when this is saving to storage/emulated/0 and not to the public Pictures folder. I have used basically this exact code in another app and it's worked fine. Does anyone know why .getExternalStoragePublic directory is not returning the accessible /Pictures/ and instead returning storage/emulated/0 ?

I have "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in my Manifest file

```
File backupFile;
File appFolder;
String path= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + "/CustomFolder";
appFolder = new File(path);
if (!appFolder.exists())
    appFolder.mkdir();
String fileName = "picture.jpg"
backupFile = new File(appFolder, fileName);
FileOutputStream output = null;
try {
    output = new FileOutputStream(backupFile);
    output.write(bytes);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    mImage.close();
    if (null != output) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `appFolder.mkdir();` Check the return value as it might fail to create the directory. Display a toast if it returns false and do not continue with the code but return.

Comment: Why are you posting all that code when the only thing that you want to say is that `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()` is a different folder than you expected. Or not?

Comment: `is not returning the accessible /Pictures/ and instead returning storage/emulated/0`. It will never return `/Pictures/` but it could return `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures`.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out. It turns out just having  "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in the Manifest file is insufficient, and I had to put the following code before it to make it work:

```
    int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this was the issue then you misinformed us as you said that the image was written. Only on a different place.